# Installation problem on my laptop with an (obviously) older processor

Tags: versions

I tried to install Linux (Ubuntu) on my 4 years old laptop and I got an error report: 
Not possible because the pc has an i686 processor. So which version is available for me?

Thanks for an answer!

Comment: And what is the CPU? I have much older computers that 4 years running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"4 years old laptop" is not enough for making decision. I have installed the latest Ubuntu 15.10 on an OLD and SLOW netbook and it worked very well on it.

What I can say is that "i686 processor" means 32bit. So, go for a 32bit version. If your RAM is low, go for a lighter desktop environment like Lubuntu. Logically you should face with no problem. It will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

you need to download version for x86 (32-bit) processor.

Go here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and in dropdown menu select 32-bit option